# USB-C hub to turn 1 USB-C port into 2/3

Tags: usb, hub

I recently got an iPad Pro and want to charge it the same time I am listening to music. I have the Apple 3.5mm jack and most adapters to turn that one port into charging + 3.5mm didn’t seem very good.

I am looking for a very simple portable hub (not a fancy dock with display-out, ethernet and what not) that just turns that usb-c port into 2, so that I can charge it and listen to music at the same time with the stuff I already have, or other potential usecases in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a [standard USB-C splitter](https://www.aukey.life/products/cbc48-usb-c-hub-2-port-usb-3-0-2-port-usb-c-1-port-usb-c-with-pd) would do the job, no?